# marionettejs - Get on which element event is generated

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have defined LayoutView & inside that region. For one region, I attached CompositeView. In CompositeView section I added ui block & trigger block like

```
   ui: {
      checkbox: '#DivGrp1 input[type=checkbox]' 
   }  

    triggers: {
      'change @ui.checkbox': 'chk:clicked'
    },
```

In parent class, I am listening the event like

```
childEvents: {
  'chk:clicked':function(e){
   // e is referring to view & not checkbox
  }
}
```

I want to access the input element on which event is raise. Here which checkbox is been checked or unchecked.

These checkboxes are dynamic.

Thanks
Aniruddha

Comment: As mentioned in the doc [LayoutView childEvents](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.4/marionette.layoutview.html#layoutview-childevents): _Take note that the first argument to a childEvents handler is the child view itself._ You need to pass a message (or a checkbox id in your case) to receive it as a second argument of the parent view's handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Access DOM in the view that owns the element. Then manually trigger event using it's `trigger` method passing the result of operation required by parent view.

I'm not marionette expert, but generally speaking it is not a good idea to directly access element's of one view from other views.

Do the operations that requires DOM access in the child view itself, if you want access to the event object, use the `events` attribute. Perform the operations and then trigger the event parent view is listening to using `trigger()` method.

Here is an: [example from the official docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/events.html#using-collectionview-s-childviewtriggers) that has a similar structure.

If you MUST have direct access to the element, then you can pass it's reference as the argument in `trigger()` method. But this isn't recommended.